# Domino and Xpage, ask to login to access a database, but not authorized

Tags: authentication, xpages, lotus-domino

I opened a demo xsp page and a window popped up asking me to input the name and password to login to the domino server. Then I entered my own id and password created in domino, but it didn't work. Only the Administrator name and its password worked. Anybody knows what's the problem?  I already edited the corresponding ACL entries.

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information: Does your user have an internet password set? What does the ACL say about your "Effective Access" to the database where the Xpage resides? Are you able to open names.nsf with your credentials in Browser? AND: This is more of a question for Server Fault than for StackExchange, as it is not about coding at all

Comment: And who has signed the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a database in a browser (no matter if classic notes web development or Xpages) one needs to meet several requirements.

First of all you need access to all NSF files that are used in the process.
As mentioned by Richard you either need to be mentioned in the ACL (namely or by group membership, or by setting `-Default-` and/or `Anonymous` to a level greater than No access).

AND the ACL has to allow Web- Access by not setting the `Maximum Internet Name and Password` to `No Access`

But this is not enough. 
To be able to do authentication you do not have an ID- file in the browser. 
You need a username and password. This password is NOT the password of your ID- file unless the admins choose to synchronize them using a policy. 
It is the password stored in your person document in the names.nsf on the server.

But still these points are not enough yet: If you have access to the server with your username and internet password (can be tested by just trying to login to `http://yourServer/names.nsf?open&login`), then you might still not be able to access the application if -as umeli pointed out in the comment- the signer of the Xpage- application does not have enough rights to sign the XPages (Server document - security).

You see: There is a lot stuff to check. But if all of these points are OK, then access to the database will not be a problem anymore.

I omitted one reason for not beeing able to login because of your error description: If the Session Authentication on your server is configured for `Multiple Servers (SSO)` then you need to use the fully qualified internet host name of the server in the URL (or at least a hostname, that contains the SSO- domain), otherwise you will be redirected to the loginpage over and over again, even after supplying the right username / password. But as you wrote about a "Window popping up" I am quite sure, that Session authentication on that server is set to "Disabled"

Comment: You also have to have access to any databases that code on the Xpage tries to access in order to load the page.

Comment: Thats what I meant with "access to all NSF files ... In the process". Thanks for clarification

Comment: I missed that you mentioned that.

Comment: @Torsten Link:   Thank you so much for your big help!  After I configured a password for internet, then everything went ok!  Again, Thank you so much!!! Your suggestions are so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could be being rejected because of the

- ACL of the NSF file not having the level of access required for operations performed in the code on the Xpage. I know you said you edited the ACL, but bear in mind that access also depends on the 'Maximum Internet Name and Password' setting for the NSF.
- ACL in other NSF files that are accessed in the code of the Xpage not having the level of access required for operations performed on it by the code. This also includes the 'Maximum Internet Name and Password' setting.

Comment: Thanks Richard,  I forgot to configure a password for internet use. After doing that, I am now able to login